# Best practice for converting an array with a single object into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have a variable such as:

```
const arr = [{foo: true, bar: 'apple', baz: 'green'}]
```

What is the best way to convert this so I just have the single object inside?

Is it to:

```
const obj = arr[0]
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: If you have a single object and always expect a single object, then `arr[0]` would be fine.

Comment: i agree to VLAZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong doing it your way, not sure if there is a "best practice" approach here.

However, another way of doing it is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const [obj] = [{foo: true, bar: 'apple', baz: 'green'}];
```

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that destructing is significantly slower than a simple array index access, also it's far less clear IMO

Comment: @Dexygen I honestly doubt the performance difference (*if any*) would have an impact on the whole application. Let's assume one approach takes 1ms, the other 2ms. Is that REALLY going to be most de-optimised part of the code?

Comment: @VLAZ It was a two-pronged argument.  I might concede the first point though I remember once revising somebody's code to use a simple object property access, so therefore not unlike an array index access, and mine was HUNDREDS of times faster, so I'm always inclined to test.  And you did not address my second point.

Comment: @Dexygen I don't need to address the second point. It's not my place to tell *you* what *you* find clear or not. I don't even know why you expect me to. I wanted to address the ever present premature micro-optimisation non-concern. People are obsessed with trying to make extremely trivial operations "faster" when that should not even be a problem. You expressed a similar concern. A single dereference is extremely unlikely to cause measurable performance loss unless you run it thousands of times in a loop. Even then, it will likely be JIT optimised.